# How to bind a sql column to a drop down list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, dropdownlistfor

I have a drop down list. I want to set its items to a column of my data base table.
how can I do?

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="MyControlsList" runat="server">
     <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

I have a table that saves the list of my controls title. I want to know how to set Items in list Item?

Comment: Could you show us your code which will reflect what efforts you have put in and what problems you are facing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you not googled your problem if you then you will get lots of answer. This is how to Bind Dropdown list.

```
DropDownList1.DataSource  = dtTable;  
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Name";
DropDownList1.DataValueField= "Id";
DropDownList.DataBind();
```

Comment: what is the dtTable? Is a data source?

Comment: @ZeynabIzadi `dtTable` is your `DataTable` object